# Iphone save files external

Tags: iphone, save, unity-game-engine

The idea is to have a save file for an iphone game that two players can exchange if needed.

So my app need to save some data somewhere in the phone. And I need to be able to "extract" the file from the phone afterwards.

Is it possible ? Where should I save the file/where am I allowed to save ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to use iTunes file sharing functionality. See [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/how-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app) for an introductory guide.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks.
Any idea without going through iTunes ?

Comment: That's the only method for manually importing/exporting files supported by the SDK that I'm aware of. To bypass iTunes, you'd have to investigate a server-based option that would allow your users to export the save file (upload to server) and then send details of that to the other players (i.e. they download the file using an in-app function). It would be more work (and cost for server overheads), but ultimately a better user experience.

Comment: Yeah I thought about the server idea but the save can be more than 300Mb in the end. So I'm trying to stick to the file system. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For a file exchange procedure, you can create local file and can transfer files via Bluetooth within the application.

If you intend to extract/get the saved file out of the app, you should create a web-service and then you can store the file on server which can be easily accessed or can be further shared with anyone.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to save objects instanced from NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary, you can use NSuserDefaults :

   NSString *obj;

   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:obj forKey:@"key"];

   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
2. Else, use NScoding with NSKeyedArchiver
3. You can save also save into a file manually but it is not recommended.